# heroku sms add-ons? -- Moonshado missing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, sms, twilio

As of 6 months ago or so [Moonshado](http://moonshado.com/) was a [Heroku](http://www.heroku.com/) featured add-on to easily add sms to one's app.  My one heroku hosted app using moonshado is still working (and billing me) and [moonshado instructions](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/moonshadosms) still appear in [Heroku's Dev Center](https://devcenter.heroku.com/).  That said, Moonshado is now absent from [Heroku's add-on page](https://addons.heroku.com/).  Indeed, no sms service seems to be be offered among Heroku's current add-ons.

Anyone know what happened to Heroku and Moonshado and what the current best way to add sms to ones new Heroku app?

Edit: 2014-06-25 -- As I detailed in an answer below, I've gotten sms to work on my rails app using [Twilio](https://www.twilio.com/).

Comment: I noticed that too and was wondering where it went. Out of curiosity what specifically were you using moonshado for?

Comment: @dkamins A scheduler app for my anesthesia dept which would send out sms's with next day operating room assignments. The current schedule is a spreadsheet posted on the web nightly 1930-2130 requiring checking and rechecking. Sms pushes the info out eliminated the need to check the web. Also, part-time employees can be put on the schedule their off days and others get assigned more than one room. sms (and validations) would help catch those problems the night before. In the end the partners making the schedule weren't excited enough about my crude prototype for me to refine/test/proceed.

Comment: Looks like [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com/) has a new add-on, [Blower.io](https://addons.heroku.com/blowerio), which offers SMS.  It's in beta and there's currently only a free version -- 30 outbound messages/mn -- but looks worth checking out.  I haven't had a chance to play with it yet myself but hope to soon.  Thanks, Heroku!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been able to get sms working on my heroku rails app using [twilio](http://www.twilio.com/).  I found [this](http://www.mutuallyhuman.com/blog/2012/01/20/twilio-on-rails/) and [this](http://www.mutuallyhuman.com/blog/2012/04/03/testing-sms-interactions-in-ruby-on-rails/) blog post by [Mutually Human](http://www.mutuallyhuman.com/) useful in getting me started.  Twilio's docs have some [great sample ruby code](https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/ruby/sms) as well.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com/) has a new add-on, [Blower.io](https://addons.heroku.com/blowerio), which offers SMS. It's in beta and there's currently only a free version -- 30 outbound messages/mn -- but looks worth checking out. I haven't had a chance to play with it yet myself but hope to soon. Thanks, Heroku! – BenU

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that my app stopped working entirely recently and Heroku support just told me that moonshado stopped working a few hours into February, 2013.  No explanation given.

Specifically, Heroku support wrote:

> Hey Ben,
>
> Moonshado stopped working a few hours into February. You'll find on
>   your Feb invoice that we switched you to the free plan effective the
>   1st of the month so that you incurred no further charges, and in March
>   we deprovisioned the add-on entirely.
>
> Best,
>
> G

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why it went missing from the addons page, but you can still add Moonshado using the CLI:

```
heroku addons:add moonshadosms:free
```

Docs (which have incorrect CLI instructions):
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/moonshadosms

Comment: consistent with moonshado no longer working with Heroku, that link no longer works...